# Compare stat command output: if: Badly formed number.

Tags: csh

I am new to csh. I want to compare the outputs of stat but it is giving me an error if: Badly formed number. Can I convert them to strings and compare? Is there any other way?
Thanks!

code is:

```
set BEFORE_TIME="`stat -c %y /home/a.xml`"

//call cpp program that might change a.xml

#if file has changed do operations
set AFTER_TIME="`stat -c %y /home/a.xml`"

if ( $BEFORE_TIME != $AFTER_TIME ) then   //This comparison is not working
    echo "File a.xml has changed"

else
    echo "File a.xml has not changed" 
endif
```

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that csh is widely considered to be a poor scripting language. See ["Csh Programming Considered Harmful"](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot) and ["Top Ten Reasons not to use the C shell"](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt). Since you're just starting out, I advise you to switch from csh to sh and/or bash, unless there's a specific reason you need to use csh. (tcsh has some nice interactive features, but bash has most of them, and zsh is even fancier.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `stat -c %y ...` is going to consist of multiple words, for example

```
2013-01-27 13:03:03.563041058 -0800
```

You've used double quotes on the `set` commands, but you need to quote the reference to the variables as well.

Change this:

```
if ( $BEFORE_TIME != $AFTER_TIME ) then
```

to this:

```
if ( "$BEFORE_TIME" != "$AFTER_TIME" ) then
```

or to this:

```
if ( $BEFORE_TIME:q != $AFTER_TIME:q ) then
```

Note that you'd run into this same problem using <strike>a real shell</strike> a different shell like `sh` or `bash`, and the solution would be the same (except that shells other than `csh` and `tcsh` don't have the `:q` suffix).